# Bootstrap DatePicker not displaying calendar icon

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-datepicker

My react component not displaying the calendar icon and even its not properly utilizing the css for selecting the date.
Import Statements:

```
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min';
```

Input element properties:

```
var elementProps = {
        id: this.props.unique,
        type: "text",
        placeholder: this.props.placeholderText,
        className: this.props.className,
        onSelect: this.onSelect,
        //readOnly: "true"
    };
```

Rendering:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div className="form-group">
            {this.renderLabel()}
            <div id={this.state.inputDateGroupId} className="input-group date">
                {React.createElement("input",this.state.elementProps)}
                <span className="input-group-addon"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Expected O/P:

[image]

Result:
[image]

I even tried `<i className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>`alternate to `<span>`

Comment: Just because you loaded the css, doesnt mean you have loaded the graphics as well.

Comment: @Xogle but when i comment the line of import CSS, then the output is complete different. So, i am confused whether it is utilizing complete CSS or just some part!

Comment: You need to load the fonts. They include the glyph icons.

Comment: @Xogle can you give me exact statement for that?

Comment: I assume you're using Webpack?

Comment: @Xogle yes, i am using webpack.

Comment: Try using this for examples on how to get webpack to load the glyphs. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/597